# Кто сталкивался с /assignment/protocol-php/ на wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

В гугле таких страниц много, но непонятно откуда они исходят?
https://www.google.ru/search?&q=%2Fassignment%2Fprotocol-php%2F

Это не созданная страница вручную, а непонятно откуда растет у меня на сайте

Comment: Это исходит из sfwd-lms , плагин  LearnDash LMS

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас нет раздела `assignment`
Добавьте в `.htaccess`

```
RedirectMatch 404 ^/assignment/.*$
```

Страницы постепенно уйдут из поисковика

Comment: Спасибо, помогло